# Where to put the files needed by the logstash configuration file on my ec2 instance?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, logstash-configuration

My logstash configuration file looks like :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/ec2-user/apache_logs"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => '%{COMMONAPACHELOG} %{QS}%{QS}'
    }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    locale => en
  }

  geoip {
      source => "clientip"
    }

  useragent {
    source => "agent"
    target => "useragent"
  }
}
.....
```

Now the path in my input is giving an error :

> This setting must be a path .. File does not exist or cannot be opened

Where should I put my apache_logs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to say which files to watch in the directory.
It can be done by modifying your `file` input like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/ec2-user/apache_logs/*.*"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
```

This will follow all files in `/home/ec2-user/apache_logs/`